# Getting Image using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Please help me understand this expression

```
Elements images = document.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
```

I don't understand the this part:

```
document.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
```

I am currently making a program that will download manga image online.

Comment: It's an element selector, basically it will find all `img` tags with png,jpg or gif on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the expression you are asking about is called a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

To quote Wikipedia,

> A regular expression is a sequence of characters that define a search
>   pattern

In your use case, the regular expression at hand is used to identify all img tags that have a src attribute with a file name that has an extension of .png or .jpg/.jpeg or .gif.

You can test it out using [this](https://regexr.com/) tool